# Does every convex planar set contain a centrally symmetric subset with at least $2/3$ its area?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, symmetry, convex-geometry

Let $S$ be a bounded convex subset of the plane of unit area. Can we guarantee the existence of a centrally-symmetric subset $C⊆ S$ of area $2/3$?

If $S$ is any triangle, this bound is tight, attained by a hexagon whose vertices are $1/3$ of the way across each side:
[image]
I suspect the triangle is the unique worst case for this problem, but didn't see a great way to prove it - perhaps there is some other convex shape which only has a centrally symmetric subset of area at most $0.6$ or something, though I would be quite surprised.

It's easy to find a $C$ with at least half the area of $S$, because every convex set contains a rectangle of at least half its area (see e.g. [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147278/largest-inscribed-rectangle-inside-a-convex-polygon) for references). How much can we improve this lower bound?

In the event of a positive resolution, I am curious whether one can find such a subset only using hexagonal $C$.

I imagine this question is discussed somewhere in the literature; if so, pointers to relevant papers or extensions to higher dimensions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is [the Kovner-Besikovich Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kovner%E2%80%93Besicovitch_measure)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this bound still holds when restricted to hexagonal subsets, or of the lower bounds in higher dimensions? I don't see anything like this mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Presumably it is better then, since the article points out that the worst are triangles.

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have miscommunicated - I am asking about the case when $C$ is restricted to be hexagonal, not when $S$ is. (Since triangles' optimal subset is always a hexagon, any decreased lower bounds would need to be witnessed by a non-triangular set.)